# ReentrantReadWriteLock (java) - nest write lock inside read lock

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

In the below code snippet, would it lead to a deadlock?

```
public class TestLocks {

ReadWriteLock lock = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();
public void add() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    //code.....

    lock.writeLock().lock();
    //code
    lock.writeLock().unlock();

    //code....
    l.readLock().unlock();
}
```

What I'm doing above is using ReentrantReadWriteLock, lock 'lock' for reading and inside it again try to acquire lock for writing (before releasing the readLock). This might never be done in production but was curious to know if the above code would lead to a deadLock?

Comment: the answer to this is in the javadoc for the class.

Comment: @jtahlborn Thanks for the pointer(+1).Per the api doc -  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html
// Must release read lock before acquiring write lock
        rwl.readLock().unlock();
        rwl.writeLock().lock();
So it's mandatory that we release the readLock before acquiring the write lock. The doc also says that 
"Additionally, a writer can acquire the read lock, but not vice-versa."
However in the code snippet which I posted above(which tried to acquire WriteLock when it only had the readLock) the compiler never gave any exception.

Comment: Compilers don't give exceptions. Do you mean (a) that the compiler never printed a compile error? If so, what error are you expecting? Or do you mean (b) that the JVM never threw an exception? If so, what exception are you expecting to be thrown?

Comment: Agree to what you said. +1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
public void add() {
    lock.readLock().lock();
    //code.....

    lock.writeLock().lock();
    //code
    lock.writeLock().unlock();

    //code....
    l.readLock().unlock();
}
```

Consider if two threads both run this same code. After the first line, they both have the read lock. Now, they both call `writeLock`. Neither thread will release its read lock until it gets a write lock. But neither thread can get a write lock until the other releases its read lock. So they can deadlock.

Comment: Why is that they "can deadlock", wouldn't the above code always end up in a deadlock.

Also, lets say there is only 1 thread which is running, wouldn't it also gets stalled i.e. the thread first acquires the readlock then it tries to acquire the write lock but it can't since readlock already  has the lock and the program will halt(cyclic dependency?) there even if it's just 1 thread.

Comment: Again this is all documented. ["Upgrading from a read lock to the write lock is not possible."](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html)

Comment: @srock The point is that it's impossible for this code not to deadlock, regardless of the specifics of the implementation of the lock. You can reason out that no reader/writer lock could make this work.

Comment: How about the other way around?  First `lock.writeLock().lock()` then `lock.readLock().lock()` ? Is it possible to deadlock?

Comment: @du369 Downgradable locks could be implemented safely.